# StringContent purpose and use in Imgur code

Tags: c#, imgur

I'm trying to follow along in an Imgur API https://apidocs.imgur.com/#5369b915-ad8b-47b1-b44b-8e2561e41cee.

One of the examples shows this:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StringContent("{{refreshToken}}"), "refresh_token");
content.Add(new StringContent("{{clientId}}"), "client_id");
content.Add(new StringContent("{{clientSecret}}"), "client_secret");
content.Add(new StringContent("refresh_token"), "grant_type");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

My understanding is that the server fills in the [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=net-7.0) information request.

If I already have the `client_id` and `client_secret`, how would I fill out this code block?

```cs
public async Task<string> GenerateAccessToken(string imgurId, string imgurSecret)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/token");
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StringContent("{{refreshToken}}"), "refresh_token");
    content.Add(new StringContent("{{clientId}}"), "client_id");
    content.Add(new StringContent("{{clientSecret}}"), "client_secret");
    content.Add(new StringContent("refresh_token"), "grant_type");
    request.Content = content;
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
}
```

Comment: The way their documentation is written, whenever you see something in double curly braces, you need to provide a value, usually from a variable in your code. For example, `new StringContent(myRefreshToken)`.